# how to get data from two different join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have two Join table first one between `alarm_id | list_id` and the other one between `list_id | car_id` what to do to get in the alarm show, the cars in each list, i tried to use has_many :cars :through => lists, but it doesn't work
any help please

Comment: You have `list_id` in hand?

Answer (score 1):

You gotta setup the associations properly. It should look something like this depending on ur requirements.

```
class Alarm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alarm_lists
  has_many :lists, through: :alarm_lists
  has_many :car_lists, through: :lists
  has_many :cars, through: :car_lists
  ...
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_lists
  has_many :cars, through: :car_lists
  ...
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_lists
  has_many :lists, through: :car_lists
  ...
end

class CarList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :list
  ...
end

class AlarmList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alarm
  belongs_to :list
  ...
end
```

for more information, check out [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: i don't have CarList model or AlarmList, but i adjusted the relations but can't know what to be written, i tried alarm.list.cars but donesn't get any result

Comment: Hmm can u show ur schema for the join tables, alarms, lists and cars...btw it should be ````alarm.lists.first.cars```` to produce any result if ur associations are correct

Comment: all goes good but when using for example alarm.cars.size in the index page it gives me an error uninitialized constant Alarm::CarsList
and highlighting the following line 
<td align='center'><%= alarm.cars %></td>

Comment: CarsList does not follow Rails convention when naming the model for join tables..it should be CarList for the model naming and car_lists for the table naming..some where in ur code or ur migrations something is not spelt correctly maybe? hope this can point u somewhere :)

Comment: i think is now the problem is not in the relation ships but in what to write in the show.html.erb, i tried alarm.lists.cars, but it gives an error

Comment: ````alarm.lists.cars```` dont makes sense; alarm.lists is a ActiveRecord CollectionProxy, like an array. You cant get the cars from a collection of lists using this syntax.

Comment: you are right, i made it as follows as two arrays inside each other
@lists.each do |list|
then inside it i got 
<% list.cars.each do |car| %>
and it is solved, but the problem now is in the .json.jbuilder file, i can't get the json for the cars, i can only get for the lists and alarms