# Laravel: How to set join to get data from two different tables and pass it to Yajra datatable

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I'm trying to load data into Yajra datatables in laravel from two different tables. In my module table Ive kept membership_id as key to maintain one to many relationship, and now I'm trying to show membership name in modules yajra datatable.

My Controller code:

```
function module(Request $request,Module $module)
{
    $memberships = Membership::where('status', true)->get();
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = Module::select('*');
        return  \DataTables::of($data)->addColumn('action', function($data) {
            return '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" id="getEditmoduleData" data-id="'.$data->id.'" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger js-sweetalert" title="Delete" data-id="'.$data->id.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeletemodulesModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="getDeleteId"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
        })->addColumn('membership', function () {
            return 
        })->editColumn('created_at', function ($request) {
            return $request->created_at->format('Y-m-d'); // human readable format
        })->filterColumn('created_at', function ($query, $keyword) {
            $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') like ?", ["%$keyword%"]); //date_format when searching using date
        })->rawColumns(['action'])->make(true);
    }
    return view("admin.module.module")->with(['memberships' => $memberships]);
}
```

Basically I'm not able to figure it out how to do join here `$data = Module::select('*');`

I've checked different links for solution, but no success. Any kind of help is welcome.

[how to get data from two different join tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813470/how-to-get-data-from-two-different-join-tables)

[How to Join two different tables in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845483/how-to-join-two-different-tables-in-laravel)

[Laravel yajra/datatables & yajra/datatables button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746247/laravel-yajra-datatables-yajra-datatables-button)

[laravel Yajra Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270559/laravel-yajra-datatable)

Comment: What happen if you change `Module::select('*');` to `Module::get();` ?

Comment: @sta It just fetching data from module table. Need title value from membership table.

Comment: @sta I've tried like $data =DB::table('module')
 ->join('memberships', 'module.membership_id', '=', 'membershis.id')
 ->select('module.id','module.title','module.description','membershis.title','module.created_at','module.updated_at','module.status')
 ->get();
But it gives me an error while passing values to yajra datatable.